# New starters to Ask Ubuntu

Tags: feature-request

As a new user to Ask Ubuntu, or for that matter any other forum based site, upon registering, it would be very useful to have some kind of basic introduction on how to ask questions. Not the process for doing so as that is fairly straight forward, but how to actually write and compose the question and subject, to best assist the people that will have to read it and answer it. I feel that this would greatly increase the efficiency of the process and make life a lot easier for those answering.

Comment: When you go to ask a question you're presented with a checklist of how to ask a good question on the side [in this guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the faq:

- https://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

These are both linked in the same page you ask a question (look on the right, by the formatting help, etc.) I've also made some videos to help:

- http://blip.tv/jorge-castro/how-to-ask-good-questionson-askubuntu-com-4927281
- http://blip.tv/jorge-castro/how-to-improve-your-questions-on-ask-ubuntu-4838345